# Performance Issue with Snowflake after creating the view

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running the below query in Snowflake and looks like the query completes it's execution in 30 seconds when applied a filter on Drug at all the stages of the query. When I create a view with the below query and run the view on the Drug in the where condition, the query is not doing that great in terms of performance. It is taking almost 5 minutes to complete it's execution.

My assumption is that the below views I am using for joining has the below row counts. Is there a way that I could improve the performance of the view that I created with the below SQL statement to match it's original execution time? Should we keep in mind any of the steps  while creating the view with the below SQL?

```
RECORDS - 827,055,369
AUDIT - 1,051,055,768
NOTES - 61,637,025
```

Any inputs would be much helpful in resolving the issues with view performance.

```
with SRC as (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         A2.DRUG
        ,A2.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
        ,A2.HOSPITAL_NAME
        ,A2.COUNTRY
        ,A2.INSTANCE
        ,A2.FORM
        ,A2.PATIENT
        ,A1.ID
        ,A1.FORM_FIELD
        ,A2.POSITION
        ,A1.AUDIT_NAME
        ,A1.VALUE
        ,A1.TIMESTAMP
    FROM AUDIT A1
    JOIN RECORDS A2
      ON A1.ID = A2.ID 
     AND A1.FORM_FIELD = A2.FORM_FIELD
    WHERE A1.DRUG = 'ABCXYZ' AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM NOTES VSN
        WHERE (1=1)
          AND VSN.DRUG = A2.DRUG
          AND VSN.ITEM_ID = A2.ITEM_ID
          AND VSN.DRUG = 'ABCXYZ'
          AND VSN.TEXT = 'Required'
    )
), MaxSourceTimestamp as (
    SELECT   WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG
        ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT
        ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID
        ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD
        ,WITH_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP
        ,MAX(WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP) AS MaxSourceTimestamp
    FROM SRC WITH_VERIFY
    JOIN SRC WITHOUT_VERIFY
       ON WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG                   = WITH_VERIFY.DRUG
      AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT                 = WITH_VERIFY.PATIENT
      AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID               = WITH_VERIFY.ID
      AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD              = WITH_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD
      AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify'
    WHERE WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP   <= WITH_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP
      AND WITH_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME = 'Verify'
    GROUP BY 
         WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG
        ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT
        ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID
        ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD
        ,WITH_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP
), FIELD_NAMES AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT DRUG, FORM_FIELD, LABEL 
    FROM FIELDS 
    WHERE DRUG = 'ABCXYZ' AND TYPE = 'CRF' 
      AND (DRUG, VERSION_ID) IN (
        SELECT DRUG, MAX(VERSION_ID) 
        FROM METADATA 
        WHERE (1=1)
          AND TYPE = 'CRF' AND DRUG = 'ABCXYZ'
        GROUP BY DRUG
      )
)
select 
     WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.HOSPITAL_NAME
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.COUNTRY
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.INSTANCE
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.POSITION
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.VALUE
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP
    ,L2.VERIFY_TIMESTAMP
    ,L3.TIMESTAMP PREVIOUS_DATE 
    ,L4.LABEL FIELD_NAME 
from SRC WITHOUT_VERIFY 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
         WITHOUT_VERIFY.*
        ,s.TIMESTAMP as VERIFY_TIMESTAMP
    FROM MaxSourceTimestamp s
    LEFT JOIN SRC WITHOUT_VERIFY
     ON WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG                   = s.DRUG
    AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT                 = s.PATIENT
    AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID               = s.ID
    AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD              = s.FORM_FIELD
    AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP        = s.MaxSourceTimestamp
    AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify'
) L2  
 on WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG            = L2.DRUG
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT          = L2.PATIENT 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID        = L2.ID 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD       = L2.FORM_FIELD 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP = L2.TIMESTAMP
LEFT JOIN SRC L3 
 ON WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG    = L3.DRUG 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT    = L3.PATIENT 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID  = L3.ID 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD = L3.FORM_FIELD
AND L3.AUDIT_NAME = 'Verify'
LEFT JOIN FIELD_NAMES L4 
 ON WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG      = L4.DRUG 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD = L4.FORM_FIELD
WHERE WITHOUT_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify';
```

Comment: Are there any clustering added to any of the tables?

Comment: I only have limited permissions to these databases i.e. just running the select queries. How to check if the clustering is added to the tables or not?

Comment: I don't see any views (create view ... yada ... yada) in your question. Are you saying that query provided runs in 30 seconds, but when you wrap it and define it as a view the performance goes up to 5 minutes?

Comment: As an aside, performance benchmarking just by run time in Snowflake can be tricky. Sometimes it could be reusing a lot of stuff from cache, but if there are no reusable cache results you bite the bullet for the whole computation. Same exact query, same exact compute resources, but very different run times.

Comment: Yes @Error_2646, you are right. when wrapped it in a view the execution time is going up to 5 minutes. When executed as a query, it just takes 30 seconds. Please note that the filter condition here is the *Drug* column. This is how my view looks like..

select * from my_new_view where Drug = 'ABCXYZ';

Comment: @san So when running the query outside of a view your have WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG = 'ABCXYZ' directly after WITHOUT_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify' at the end of the query?

Comment: So if you add to the final WHERE clause in the above SQL “and WITHOUT_VERIFY. Drug = 'ABCXYZ' “ it runs in 30s? What’s the difference in the EXPLAIN PLANs for the query above compared to using the view?

Comment: @san If I recall correctly, maybe Snowflake caching has gotten more sophisticated in the few years since I took their training course. But the caching was done by hashing the actual text of the query, so any changes, even an extra space would flummox the cache. It'd be interesting to change your query, just add a dummy condition like AND 2 = 2 and see whether the performance is impacted.

Comment: @san Makes it very delicate to performance baseline because someone else might have run the same query in warehouse, so unbeknownst to you there's an optimization with cache.

Comment: @Error_2646, I just updated my SQL with the Drug filter at various sections of the SQL, please have a look at it. 
I am running these 2 statements before each SQL run.

alter session set USE_CACHED_RESULT = false;
alter warehouse <wh_name> suspend;

Please let me know if there is no necessity to run this.

Comment: @san That's a good idea for the benchmark. So when you run that what are your execution times? Also, if it doesn't violate your company's security rules, putting the respective explain plans side-by-side would be really informative.

Comment: After turning off the result set cache, run the query and see how many micropartitions are scanned when using a view vs. when using the query not in a view. The most likely reason this is happening is that the predicates when sent through the view are not being pushed down to the table scans for pruning. If you see a much higher partition count scan when using the view vs. the SQL not using a view, there are some options you can try. One option is to use a SQL UDTF and place the predicates exactly where you want them as input parameters to the UDTF.

Answer (score 1):

My old company found it the past, sometimes, complex VIEWs can fail to push filters down, which results in some part that could have done a "lot of filtering" to not, and a whole table is loaded, operated on, and thrown away. This happened more if the view was used inside complex other SQL, or just with phases of the moon (aka after release Wednesdays and the optimizer was altered in some way).

To be fair, SQL Server has the exact edge case also, it's mostly an optimizer thing.

Given the CTE SRC is getting smashed, there are some permutations, you note in your answer that when the SQL is a view, you use code like:

```
select * from my_new_view where Drug = 'ABCXYZ';
```

which implies those `drug = 'ABCXYZ'` are not in SRC, thus will be a major slow down, as all three tables are effectively smashing the heck out of that filter.

one option is to use [Tabular SQL UDFs (UDTFs)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions) to force the filter into the SQL thus not have a view, but have SQL macro that forces the use of drug filter:

```
select * from table(my_new_udtf('ABCXYZ'));
```

and now the filter can be in always limiting the data very early. This is how we worked around stuff to make sure we always had performance.

### SQL changes:

There are number of things this SQL is doing that implies "there is too much data, quick clean it up" like the distinct at the top of SRC. If this is not actually needed, it is costly, and if it is needed, it would make more sense to fource it earlier into the sub-selects, thus the results of the a1,a2 join
of `SRC` would be smaller, and known distinct. Also the EXIST could be swapped to a JOIN of distinct values, and again might be faster. But SRC might be the bottle neck that is most likely the self join of SRC in MaxSourceTimestamp (but onto that later).

SRC could get rewritten like to move the distinct prior to the JOIN like so:

```
with SRC as (
    SELECT  
         A2.DRUG
        ,A2.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
        ,A2.HOSPITAL_NAME
        ,A2.COUNTRY
        ,A2.INSTANCE
        ,A2.FORM
        ,A2.PATIENT
        ,A1.ID
        ,A1.FORM_FIELD
        ,A2.POSITION
        ,A1.AUDIT_NAME
        ,A1.VALUE
        ,A1.TIMESTAMP
    FROM (
        select DISTINCT
            id
            ,form_field
            ,audit_name
            ,value
            ,timestamp
        from audit
        where drug = 'ABCXYZ'
    ) as A1
    JOIN (
        select DISTINCT
            id
            ,form_field
            ,DRUG
            ,HOSPITAL_NUMBER
            ,HOSPITAL_NAME
            ,COUNTRY
            ,INSTANCE
            ,FORM
            ,PATIENT
            ,POSITION
            ,ITEM_ID
        from RECORDS
        where drug = 'ABCXYZ' /* because a2.drug = vsn.drug "and" vsn.drug = 'ABCXYZ' */
    ) as A2
        ON A1.ID = A2.ID 
            AND A1.FORM_FIELD = A2.FORM_FIELD
    JOIN (
        select distinct
            drug
            ,ITEM_ID
        from NOTES
        where DRUG = 'ABCXYZ'
            and VSN.TEXT = 'Required'
    ) as j_vsn
        on VSN.DRUG = A2.DRUG
          AND VSN.ITEM_ID = A2.ITEM_ID

)
```

but this code is very heavy on that `DRUG = 'ABCXYZ'` which if not in the VIEW, is the source of your slow down, but perhaps we can make the whole thing fast enough, that not a problem.

I am guessing `MaxSourceTimestamp` is your bottle neck. That self join could be replaced with a LAG and thus avoid the GROUP BY (but that aggregate cost is in the LAG but you avoid the ROW explotion of the JOIN)..

so your code is like this example code:

```
with data(drug, PATIENT, id, timestamp, AUDIT_NAME) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10, 100, 1010, 'Verify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1009, 'NonVerify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1008, 'NonVerify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1005, 'Verify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1003, 'NonVerify')
)
select
    wov.drug
    ,wov.patient
    ,wov.id
    ,wv.timestamp
    ,max(wov.timestamp)
from data as wv
join data as wov
    ON wov.DRUG = wv.DRUG
            AND wov.PATIENT = wv.PATIENT
            AND wov.ID = wv.ID
            AND wov.AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify'
    WHERE wov.TIMESTAMP   <= wv.TIMESTAMP
      AND wv.AUDIT_NAME = 'Verify'
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

which gives:

[image]

which can be change to:

```
with data(drug, PATIENT, id, timestamp, AUDIT_NAME) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10, 100, 1010, 'Verify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1009, 'NonVerify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1008, 'NonVerify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1005, 'Verify'),
        (1, 10, 100, 1003, 'NonVerify')
)
select
    drug
    ,patient
    ,id
    ,timestamp
    ,lag(iff(AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify', timestamp, null)) ignore nulls over (partition by drug, patient, id order by timestamp) as lag_ts
from data
qualify AUDIT_NAME = 'Verify'
```

giving:

[image]

thus your `MaxSourceTimestamp` should become

```
), MaxSourceTimestamp as (
    SELECT   
        DRUG
        ,PATIENT
        ,ID
        ,FORM_FIELD
        ,TIMESTAMP
        ,LAG(iff(AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify', timestamp, null)) ignore nulls over (partition by drug, patient, id, FORM_FIELD order by timestamp) AS MaxSourceTimestamp
    FROM SRC
    qualify AUDIT_NAME = 'Verify'
        
)
```

And then there is the problem, `MaxSourceTimestamp` did join SRC twice to get the "most recent non verify timestamp, which you join to SRC again in L2 to get all the "prior non-verified rows columns" but outside of  to select everything, but really you are only using the timestamp of the verify row.

the join to SRC inside L2 is not needed, it currently is:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
         wov.*
        ,s.TIMESTAMP as VERIFY_TIMESTAMP
    FROM MaxSourceTimestamp as s
    LEFT JOIN SRC as wov
        ON wov.DRUG = s.DRUG
            AND wov.PATIENT = s.PATIENT
            AND wov.ID = s.ID
            AND wov.FORM_FIELD = s.FORM_FIELD
            AND wov.TIMESTAMP = s.MaxSourceTimestamp
            AND wov.AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify'
) L2  
    on WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG = L2.DRUG
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT = L2.PATIENT 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID = L2.ID 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD = L2.FORM_FIELD 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP = L2.TIMESTAMP
```

but could be:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        s.drug
        ,s.PATIENT
        ,s.ID
        ,s.MaxSourceTimestamp as TIMESTAMP
        ,s.TIMESTAMP as VERIFY_TIMESTAMP    
    FROM MaxSourceTimestamp as s
) L2  
    on WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG = L2.DRUG
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT = L2.PATIENT 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID = L2.ID 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD = L2.FORM_FIELD 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP = L2.TIMESTAMP
```

and that could be reworked to just be a join, like how L3 is done, BUT L3 feels completely not needed, and is called "previous date" but has no prior time filter, so really could be the future dates also.. and could be many rows.. (I think I am seeing why the distinct is there)..

### final sql:

So this makes your "base SQL" look like:

```
with SRC as (
    SELECT  
         A2.DRUG
        ,A2.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
        ,A2.HOSPITAL_NAME
        ,A2.COUNTRY
        ,A2.INSTANCE
        ,A2.FORM
        ,A2.PATIENT
        ,A1.ID
        ,A1.FORM_FIELD
        ,A2.POSITION
        ,A1.AUDIT_NAME
        ,A1.VALUE
        ,A1.TIMESTAMP
    FROM (
        select DISTINCT
            id
            ,form_field
            ,audit_name
            ,value
            ,timestamp
        from audit
        where drug = 'ABCXYZ'
    ) as A1
    JOIN (
        select DISTINCT
            id
            ,form_field
            ,DRUG
            ,HOSPITAL_NUMBER
            ,HOSPITAL_NAME
            ,COUNTRY
            ,INSTANCE
            ,FORM
            ,PATIENT
            ,POSITION
            ,ITEM_ID
        from RECORDS
        where drug = 'ABCXYZ' /* because a2.drug = vsn.drug "and" vsn.drug = 'ABCXYZ' */
    ) as A2
        ON A1.ID = A2.ID 
            AND A1.FORM_FIELD = A2.FORM_FIELD
    JOIN (
        select distinct
            drug
            ,ITEM_ID
        from NOTES
        where DRUG = 'ABCXYZ'
            and VSN.TEXT = 'Required'
    ) as j_vsn
        on VSN.DRUG = A2.DRUG
          AND VSN.ITEM_ID = A2.ITEM_ID

), MaxSourceTimestamp as (
    SELECT   
        DRUG
        ,PATIENT
        ,ID
        ,FORM_FIELD
        ,TIMESTAMP
        ,LAG(iff(AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify', timestamp, null)) ignore nulls over (partition by drug, patient, id, FORM_FIELD order by timestamp) AS MaxSourceTimestamp
    FROM SRC
    qualify AUDIT_NAME = 'Verify'
        
), FIELD_NAMES AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DRUG, 
        FORM_FIELD, 
        LABEL 
    FROM FIELDS 
    WHERE DRUG = 'ABCXYZ' 
        AND TYPE = 'CRF' 
        AND (DRUG, VERSION_ID) IN (
            SELECT DRUG, MAX(VERSION_ID) 
            FROM METADATA 
            WHERE TYPE = 'CRF' 
                AND DRUG = 'ABCXYZ'
            GROUP BY DRUG
      )
)
select 
     WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.HOSPITAL_NAME
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.COUNTRY
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.INSTANCE
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.POSITION
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.VALUE
    ,WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP
    ,L2.VERIFY_TIMESTAMP
    ,L3.TIMESTAMP PREVIOUS_DATE 
    ,L4.LABEL FIELD_NAME 
from SRC as WITHOUT_VERIFY 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        s.drug
        ,s.PATIENT
        ,s.ID
        ,s.MaxSourceTimestamp as TIMESTAMP
        ,s.TIMESTAMP as VERIFY_TIMESTAMP    
    FROM MaxSourceTimestamp as s
) L2  
    on WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG = L2.DRUG
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT = L2.PATIENT 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID = L2.ID 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD = L2.FORM_FIELD 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.TIMESTAMP = L2.TIMESTAMP
LEFT JOIN SRC as L3 
    ON WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG  = L3.DRUG 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.PATIENT = L3.PATIENT 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.ID = L3.ID 
        AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD = L3.FORM_FIELD
        AND L3.AUDIT_NAME = 'Verify'
LEFT JOIN FIELD_NAMES L4 
 ON WITHOUT_VERIFY.DRUG      = L4.DRUG 
AND WITHOUT_VERIFY.FORM_FIELD = L4.FORM_FIELD
WHERE WITHOUT_VERIFY.AUDIT_NAME != 'Verify';
```

and I believe this will perform a lot better